# It is necessary for a windows installer to write to registary (compiled python app installed with NSIS)

Tags: python, installation, registry, executable, nsis

I have an application written in python, compiled to .exe with pyinstller that I would like to distribute with the installer NSIS.

Currently the installer unpacks to Program Files (x86) and creates desktop shortcuts, however does not write to registery. Having read some tutorials I see installers generally write a reference to the installed software to the windows registery, but it is not clear if this is always done. Is this really necessary? My app is standalone and I would like to avoid writing to registery if I can.

Any references for futher reading would be much appreciated as am having trouble finding much on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing to the registry is optional but if you are distributing your app in a installer instead of a zip file then it is pretty common to register your uninstaller so that it is displayed in the control panel.

The NSIS documentation tells you [where and what to write](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/AppendixD.html#useful_add_uninst_infos).